# Set the output for image-webpack-loader

Tags: npm, webpack, configuration-files

I'm trying to load images through the image-webpack-loader module, it works correctly, but instead of saving the image where the `outputPath` indicates, it saves it in the root directory of the project, does anyone know how to define the output of the images? I have read the entire documentation ([webpack-image-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader)) and I can not find any place where it says how to configure the output of files. Here I leave the my webpack.config.js

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

module.exports = {
entry: ['./assets/src/scss/index.scss', './assets/src/service/clanService.js', './assets/src/service/locationService',
    './assets/src/model/Clan.js', './assets/src/model/Location.js', './assets/src/model/Player.js',
    './assets/src/utils/material.js', './assets/src/utils/constants.js', './assets/src/utils/auxFunctions.js',
    './assets/src/fonts/Supercell-magic-webfont.generated.woff','./assets/src/images/Clash_Royale.png'],
output: {
    filename: './dist/bundle.js',
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
            use: [
                'file-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    options: {
                        bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
                        disable: true, // webpack@2.x and newer
                        outputPath: '/dist/images/' // <-- Thats not work
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /^(?!.*\.generated\.ttf$).*\.ttf$/,
            use: ['css-loader', 'fontface-loader'],
        }, {
            test: /\.generated.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    outputPath: '/dist/fonts/',
                },
            }],
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: './dist/bundle.css',
                    },
                },
                {loader: 'extract-loader'},
                {loader: 'css-loader'},
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
                    },
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015'],
                plugins: ['transform-object-assign']
            },
        }
    ],
  },
}
```

As you can see I also have to enter the files one by one at the `entry` point, is it possible to add whole directories?

Answer (score 2):

Answering a pretty old post here but I had the same issue today.

At least it may help someone else having the same problem.

Setting the `outputPath` for `file-loader` prior to `image-webpack-loader` solved it for me.

```
{
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                outputPath: '/dist/images/'
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: { ... }
        }
    ]
}
```